# Can I include the default group to greenkeeper.json when other groups also exist

Tags: greenkeeper

**Background**

I've just added a `greenekeeper.json` file to an already existing (and Greenkeeper enabled) repo to account for additional `package.json` files that were not previously being monitored by Greenkeeper.

**greenkeeper.json**

```
{
  "groups": {
    "default": {
      "packages": [
        "package.json"
      ]
    },
    "libs": {
      "packages": [
        "packages/lib1/package.json",
        "packages/lib2/package.json",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Observation**

I see an initial PR for the `libs` group, but I don't see an initial PR for the default group.

**Question**

Can I not have a `default` group, when additional groups (in addition to `default`) are included?

(i.e. Do I need to rename the `default` group to something else...?)

**Full Disclosure**

In my first `greenkeeper.json` commit, I had included all `package.json` files in the `default` group.  This commit, predictably, generated an initial Greenkeeper PR, and that PR included library version updates for all `package.json` files (including root level `package.json`).

After my second `greenkeeper.json` commit, Greenkeeper deleted that initial PR, and subsequently created new PRs for each new group, but, it did not generate a PR for the updated `default` group...so maybe Greenkeeper doesn't create initial PRs for groups that have just been modified (only for those that are newly created)...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official response from Greenkeeper (from an email exchange):

```
An initial branch will only be created for new groups, or groups that have new repositories in them.
```

Since the `default` group existed before and there were no new `package.json` files in that group, no new initial PR commit was created (even though this is the initial `greenkeeper.json`).

When I re-named that group to `root`, I did get a new initial PR from Greenkeeper.

```
Can I not have a default group, when additional groups (in addition to default) are included?
```

You can have a `default` group even when there are additional groups in `greenkeeper.json`.

```
Do I need to rename the default group to something else...?
```

Only if you want Greenkeeper to generate a new initial PR.